# Factor polynomial equations in Python?

Tags: python, math

like i mean this type of decomp:

`2x^2 - 2x - 4`

`2x^2 + 2x - 4x - 4`

`2x(x + 1) - 4(x + 1)`

`(2x - 4)(x + 1)`

i tried finding out how online and working in python and could not find anything
i got a big mess of a loop that i made trying to make it and  am lost

i got pretty close to getting my question solved here but had no luck
https://hackernoon.com/how-to-do-calculus-with-python-derivatives-cheat-sheet-part-1-zfv3uno

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Comment: You could try sympy, the symbolic math library.  `(2*x**2 - 2*x - 4).factor()` would give `2*(x - 2)*(x + 1)`.  If you want to keep the original notation, you'd need `expr = parse_expr(s, transformations=(standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,) + (convert_xor,)))` and  `print(expr.factor())`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you that replaces ^ for **, eg 2^5 ==> 2**5
you must explicit express operations: 3x in equations should be like 3*x and (2x - 4)(x + 1) (2x - 4)*(x + 1)

Comment: my plan is user inputs from a tkinter entry that has them enter a b c that splits at spaces in this example input would be 2 -2 -4 and output would be (2x-4)(x+1)

Comment: This is not an answer. Once you gain enough reputation, you will be able to provide comments.